# Crashing when i put simple int variable

Tags: c, input

I have simple input function that works:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *first;
    char *last;

    scanf("%s", first);

    printf("%s", last);

    return 1;
}
```

But when i start to expand my work, and put simple counter, programs crash:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *first;
    char *last;

    scanf("%s", first);

    printf("%s", last);

    return 1;
}
```

any idea ?

Comment: aren't you supposed to allocate your char* before trying to access them?

Comment: Your simple function does **not** work.

Comment: You're supposed to *assign* a variable a value before you *use* its value. You don't do this for `first` or `last`.

Comment: @meagar: It's actually worse than that—it's not that it doesn't work; it's that it _shouldn't_ work, but _might anyway_ if you get unlucky, which is the worst kind of invalid code.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *first;

scanf("%s", first);
```

`first` is not initialized before you call `scanf`: its value before the call is an invalid address.

Comment: it may also be good to use a construct like `while(scanf("%s",first)!=0){...}` to check if the input was a character string

Comment: +1 for a great, concise answer—but it doesn't explain why adding `int i = 0;` makes a difference.

Comment: @abarnert the program invokes undefined behavior and undefined is undefined.

Comment: @ouah: Yes, but it's useful to understand why, with real-world compilers, undefined behavior sometimes "does the right thing" (or at least seems to) and other times doesn't. That usually hits home the message about taking undefined behavior seriously.

Answer (score 1):

You'll either want to dynamically allocate your `char*` before using `scanf()` to store into it or perhaps switch to a character array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `first` is an uninitialized pointer variable, meaning the pointer has an arbitrary value—it could be pointing anywhere in memory.

If you get very lucky, it ends up pointing to unused, allocated memory, so reading a string into it happens to work.

If you get lucky, it ends up pointing to an unmapped address, so reading a string into it causes a segfault.

If you get unlucky, it ends up pointing to some valid memory that holds something else, so it seems to work, but overwrites other data (or code), causing mysterious hard-to-debug crashes, incorrect results, or security holes.

---

Adding `int i = 0;` doesn't really change anything, except to "re-roll the dice". You could also get different results by, e.g., changing the compiler flags (especially if you turn debugging or optimization features on or off).

---

For example, maybe the area the stack gets allocated from looks like this when your `main` function is entered:

```
pointer to return address in the middle of libc
pointer to data segment
0
```

In the first version of your code, you don't initialize anything, and `first` ends up inheriting the value of the pointer to the data segment, so scanning into it works. In the second version, `i` ends up inheriting the pointer to the data segment (and overwriting it with `0`), while `first` ends up inheriting the `0` value, so scanning into it segfaults.

---

If you're interested in seeing what's really going on, you can look at the assembly generated by the `-S` flag (or equivalent for your compiler), or you can just `printf("%p\n", first)` and then see what address you get and figure out what gets mapped there.

But really, it doesn't matter *why* it doesn't work. It's not supposed to work, and the only solution is to properly initialize the pointer to something valid (as ouah's answer and the others explain).

Answer (score 0):

Your `first` variable is not initialized. Either declare it as array or allocate dynamically based on your need.

1. Array version,

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       char first[ SIZE ];     // define SIZE as per your need
       char last[ SIZE ];

       scanf("%s", first);
       printf("%s", last);     // FIXME : last is again not initialized
       return 1;
   }
   ```
2. Dynamic version,

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       char *first = malloc( SIZE );     // define SIZE as per your need
       char *last = malloc( SIZE );

       scanf("%s", first);
       printf("%s", last);     // FIXME : last is again not initialized

       free( first ); first = NULL;
       free( last ); last = NULL;

       return 1;
   }
   ```